# Private message Slack user via RTM

Tags: node.js, poker, slack-api

Has anyone figured out how to private message a user via Slack RTM? I'm trying to create a game and would like to PM a user in Slack to provide updates and such.

You can see how far I am via the coffee script in src/poker.coffee in https://github.com/robksawyer/hubot-poker.

Feel free to fork and finish. ;)

And please let me know if I'm way off track and if this isn't possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs

> You can send a message to a private group or direct message channel in the same way, but using a Group ID (C024BE91L) or DM channel ID (D024BE91L).

So you just need to specify the recipient `@username` or id of the DM `D1234BLah` as the value for `channel` when sending the message to the RTM API e.g.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "message",
    "channel": "@jeff",
    "text": "hello jeff"
}
```

Full RTM docs here: https://api.slack.com/rtm